# ffmpeg how to shorten volume range

Tags: ffmpeg

I use this command below to get volume information

```
ffmpeg -i {fileName} -af  "volumedetect" -f null -
```

and get result below:

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] mean_volume: -25.1 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] max_volume: -4.0 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_4db: 12
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_5db: 72
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_6db: 293
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_7db: 808
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_8db: 2276
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_9db: 5885
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_10db: 13146
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_11db: 26627
```

I want to shorten volume range to half range like this below

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_6db: ...
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_7db: ...
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_8db: ...
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 000001b4f9675ec0] histogram_9db: ...
```

How to do it by ffmpeg command?

**Update1:**

filename.mp3 volume detect is below:

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] max_volume: -0.3 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] histogram_0db: 32
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] histogram_1db: 333
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] histogram_2db: 1216
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] histogram_3db: 3490
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] histogram_4db: 8829
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 00000192cd9adcc0] histogram_5db: 19873
```

after execute command

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp3 -af filename_output.mp3
```

filename_output.mp3 volume detect is below:

```
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] max_volume: -0.4 dB
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] histogram_0db: 13
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] histogram_1db: 226
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] histogram_2db: 906
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] histogram_3db: 2688
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] histogram_4db: 7202
[Parsed_volumedetect_0 @ 0000017af506dd00] histogram_5db: 16473
```

There is no big changes, if I want to shorten more volume range , how to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have be able to achieve this using [FFMPEG's Dynamic Audio Normalizer (dynaudnorm)](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#dynaudnorm) feature. From the docs:

> Normalizer achieves this goal *without* applying "dynamic range compressing". It will retain 100% of the dynamic range *within* each section of the audio files.

In effect there will be a change in the total amount of decibels between parts of the audio. However, the changes will be relative to each part to minimise distortion in the audio. The command should look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af dynaudnorm output.mp3
```

In the snippet above I am using mp3 as an example. This should work with all ffmpeg supported formats.

Comment: I already try this, there is no big changes, if I want to shorten more volume range , how to do?